# How do I URL encode this

Tags: python

Need this:

```
POST&https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.trademe.co.nz%2FOauth%2FRequestToken&oauth_callback%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.website-tm-access.co.nz%252Ftrademe-callback%26oauth_consumer_key%3DC74CD73FDBE37D29BDD21BAB54BC70E422%26oauth_nonce%3D7O3kEe%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1285532322%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26scope%3DMyTradeMeRead%252CMyTradeMeWrite
```

Myattempt:

```
New_base_string ="POST&https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.trademe.co.nz%2FOauth%2FRequestToken&oauth_callback%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.website-tm-access.co.nz%252Ftrademe-callback%26oauth_consumer_key%" + str(consumer_key) +"3DC74CD73FDBE37D29BDD21BAB54BC70E422%26oauth_nonce%3" + str(nonce) + "%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3" + str(time) + "%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26scope%3DMyTradeMeRead%252CMyTradeMeWrite"
```

I just tried to append it to the end, will this work or will i need to append to a list and then encode?

so like this:

```
headers = { my_variable + other_variable }

authorization = '5C82CC6BC7C6472154FBC9CAB24A29A2 ' + ', '.join([key + '="' + urllib.parse.quote_plus(str(value)) + '"' for key, value in headers.items()])
```

Comment: It looks like the string is partially encoded, some parts maybe encoded twice. Can you first try it here http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ and tell us what input and output you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## General

If you want to URL encode parameters to your POST request the best way is:

```
import urllib

f = { 'eventName' : 'myEvent', 
      'eventDescription' : 'cool event', 
      'url' : 'http://www.google.com'}

print 'POST&%s' % urllib.urlencode(f)
```

**Output:**

```
POST&eventName=myEvent&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&eventDescription=cool+event
```

with Dictionary its not ordered if you want to order it just use a list

```
import urllib

f = [ ('eventName', 'myEvent'), 
      ('eventDescription', 'cool event'), 
      ('url', 'http://www.google.com')]

print 'POST&%s' % urllib.urlencode(f)
```

**Output**

```
POST&eventName=myEvent&eventDescription=cool+event&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com
```

## How to get your need this string (Python 3.5)

While the general example is tested in python 2.7, I wrote your example with python 3.5 code.

```
import urllib.parse

method = "POST"
url = "https://secure.trademe.co.nz/Oauth/RequestToken"

params = [('oauth_callback', 'http://www.website-tm-access.co.nz/trademe-callback'),
            ('oauth_consumer_key', 'C74CD73FDBE37D29BDD21BAB54BC70E422'),
            ('oauth_nonce', '7O3kEe'),
            ('oauth_signature_method', 'HMAC-SHA1'),
            ('oauth_timestamp', 1285532322),
            ('oauth_version', 1.0),
            ('scope', "MyTradeMeRead,MyTradeMeWrite")]

print('POST&%(url)s&%(params)s' %  { 'url' : urllib.parse.quote_plus(url), 'params' : urllib.parse.quote_plus(urllib.parse.urlencode(params)) })
```

**Output**

```
POST&https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.trademe.co.nz%2FOauth%2FRequestToken&oauth_callback%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.website-tm-access.co.nz%252Ftrademe-callback%26oauth_consumer_key%3DC74CD73FDBE37D29BDD21BAB54BC70E422%26oauth_nonce%3D7O3kEe%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1285532322%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26scope%3DMyTradeMeRead%252CMyTradeMeWrite
```

Comment: is urllib.parse.quote the 3.3 alternative for urllib.quote_plus ? and urllib.urlencode for urllib.parse.urlencode?

Comment: @musss just looking you need it for python 3.3?

Comment: @musss i updated your example to use with python 3.5. It should work with python 3.3 too ... just `import urllib.parse` and then use `urllib.parse.quote_plus` etc.